# Face detection on Samsung devices

Tags: android, face-detection, samsung-mobile

I use android face detection API with Camera.FaceDetectionListener .

I have several tablets.

- A Galaxy Tab GT-P5110 2 version 4.0.3 (Kernel: 3.0.8-365113-user dpi DELL155 @ # 1)
- A Galaxy Tab GT-P5110 2 version 4.1.1 (Kernel: 3.0.31-523998 se.infra @ SEP-98 # 1)
- A Galaxy Tab GT-P5210 3 version 4.2.2 (Kernel: 3.4.34-1135839 se.infra @ S0210-10 # 1)

The detection works perfectly on the first but on the second Tab 2, as soon as I turn on face detection, preview flick and detection is slow.

On Tab 3, the listener is never invoked as if it did not detect any faces.

I also tried this sample : http://developer.samsung.com/android/samples/Mad-Hatter-Face-Recogition
but I have the same issues.

Is there a known bug on Samsung devices ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is known that Samsung's devices perform differently. So you have to treat different Samsung's device carefully. You can use two steps to investigate this issue: 1. pass a bitmap directly to the detection API to check whether it can work. 2. check the preview FPS. maybe you have to set different parameters to improve camera performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Reduce the number of FPS does not solve the issue. I use Face.Detector instead of new FaceDetection and I have good result if I reduce preview quality. I hope Samsung will do something for that.

Comment: Yeah, there's always some weird compatibility issue appear on Samsung's devices. :) They customize too much stuff, sometimes they are not able to cover all things.